# Which libraries are needed to run sklearn.GradientBoostingClassifier in AWS lambda?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I want to set up an `sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier` object in AWS Lambda. I want my deployment package to be as light as possible.

The model will receive one string per call that contains *k* features. The program will parse this string to convert it to an array of shape `(k, 1)`, pass it to the classifier and return a predicted probability.

Given the model and input string, what are the bare minimum dependencies that would allow me to return a predicted probability in AWS Lambda?

To make this replicable on your end, suppose my classifier was trained follows:

```py
# Import libraries for training
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from pickle import dump

# Load data
X = load_breast_cancer()['data']
y = load_breast_cancer()['target']

# Initialize and fit classifier
clf = GradientBoostingClassifier(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)

# Dump that bad boy
dump(clf, open('my_model.pkl', 'wb'))
```

I only want to load this model, feed the features to it and return a predicted a probability. For this example, suppose I have already parsed the string and converted it to a numpy array:

```py
# Suppose I have already turned the string into a numpy array
import numpy as np
new_obs = np.array([1.799e+01, 1.038e+01, 1.228e+02, 1.001e+03, 1.184e-01, 2.776e-01,
                    3.001e-01, 1.471e-01, 2.419e-01, 7.871e-02, 1.095e+00, 9.053e-01,
                    8.589e+00, 1.534e+02, 6.399e-03, 4.904e-02, 5.373e-02, 1.587e-02,
                    3.003e-02, 6.193e-03, 2.538e+01, 1.733e+01, 1.846e+02, 2.019e+03,
                    1.622e-01, 6.656e-01, 7.119e-01, 2.654e-01, 4.601e-01, 1.189e-01])

# Load model
from pickle import load
clf = load(open('my_model.pkl', 'rb'))))

# Predict probability
clf.predict_proba(new_obs.reshape(30, 1))
> 0.001246233441897731
```

My goal is to return the float `0.001246233441897731`. Given that I only want to load the model, pass an array to it and use `predict_proba`, what are the minimum libraries needed to run this script?

Comment: The easiest way is to install the entire `sklearn` lib unless you want to spend the time tweaking it and stripping away the files that's not needed

Comment: If I understand correctly, sklearn uses matplotlib, scipy, iPython, etc. Given that I will not use anything related to some of these libraries, is there any way to shave some dependencies off?

Comment: Shaving the dependencies is pretty time-consuming and can lead to weird bugs. I would not recommend doing it unless you know what you are doing. tldr, there is no easy way to do this.